# Can not move to the next item using Gallery- Android 2.3?

Tags: android, gallery

I'm facing with a weird problem with Gallery in Android.

I'm using Gallery for display a list of item. It works perfectly on real device and most emulator. When I scroll to the next item ( near the last item of the list) it gets stuck, and can not move to the next item. The strange thing is it's only appear on Emulator android 2.3 on a specific computer (my laptop and others have no problem). Only my friend's computer runs emulator 2.3 get this issue. I have no idea about how to fix that.

Could you please suggess some ideas about this?.
Thank you.

Update!

Let me describe my problem a bit.
I have a list contains 4 item.
call: A B C D

When I scroll from A->B its Ok.
when I scroll from B-C its not Ok. It gets stuck in item B and can not move to item C.

Thank you.

Comment: debug it there and figure out why the crash

Comment: There is no crash, please review my updated question. Thank you